# Plotting the electric field of the Lienard-Wiechert potentials

Tags: plotting, function-construction, vector-calculus

I am having a very rough time trying to properly define and then vectorplot the expression for the electric field of the Lienard-Wiechert potentials I have been trying to code. Up to this point, the code I have in place for the scalar and vector potentials works and produces *something*, but I cannot get these into an electric field equation. What I have so far is the following, please excuse the length:

The constants used

```
q = 1; (*elementary charge*)
c = 1;(*speed of light*)
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1;(*vacuum permittivity of free space*)
\[Mu] = 1;(*vacuum permeability of free space*)
u = 0.1*c;
```

Point charge equation of motion, retarded time expression, field point location

```
xs[t_] := (u*Cos[30 Degree]*t) ;(*x-pos of source*)
ys[t_] := (u*Sin[30 Degree]*t) ;(*y-pos of source*)
rs[t_] := {xs[t], ys[t]};(*location of the source*)
v[t_] = D[rs[t], t];(*velocity of source*)

r = {x, y};(*location of the field point*)

tr[r_, t_] := t - Norm[r - rs[t]]/c (*the retarded time as a function of the separation distance
 and time elapsed*)
```

Expressions for the Lienard-Wiechert scalar and vector potentials

```
LWS[r_, t_] := (1/(4*Pi*\[CurlyEpsilon]))*(q*c/
      (Norm[r - rs[t]]*c -
        Dot[r - rs[t], v[tr[r, t]]]));(*equation for the Lienard-Wiechert scalar potential*)

LWV[r_, t_] := (\[Mu]/4*Pi) (q*c*v[tr[r, t]]/
      (Norm[r - rs[t]]*c -
        Dot[r - rs[t], v[tr[r, t]]]));(*equation for the Lienard-Wiechert vector potential*)
```

And FINALLY, this is how I am *trying* to get an expression for the electric field that is plottable

```
LWVdt = D[LWV[r, t], t];
LWSgrad = Grad[LWS[r, t], {r}];
LWEField[r_, t_] := -LWSgrad - LWVdt;(*LW electric field equation*)
```

The issue is that defining LWEField as I have produces the Tag List error message that **[r_,t_] is protected.** Thing is, is that the field is a literal function of *r* and *t*, so I do not understand how to get a plot of it without specifying it as a function of those variables. Could part of the issue be all the SetDelay I have throughout? Again I deeply apologize for the volume of this question. Even a nudge in the right direction would be great; I am wanting to know where I went wrong so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Tag List error; posting your plot code may yield some insight.

That being said, it plots fine with three changes:

1. make LWVdt and LWSgrad functions of $t$,
2. replace instances of $|x|^2$ with $x^2$ (`Norm` inserts absolute values which mess with the derivatives), and
3. call `Grad` with `r` instead of `{r}`.

So the last box of code becomes

```
Remove[LWVdt,LWSgrad,LWEField]
LWVdt[t_] = D[LWV[r, t] /.Abs@x_^2:>x^2, t];
LWSgrad[t_] = Grad[LWS[r, t] /.Abs@x_^2:>x^2, r];
LWEField[r_, t_] := -LWSgrad@t - LWVdt@t;(*LW electric field equation*)
```

Then `Plot3D[Evaluate@LWEField[r,0],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4}]` yields

[image: t=0]

which may or may not be the right surfaces.

Comment: Holy cow that plot looks so pretty, thank you for the promptness delivered! I do have two questions though: for one, could you elaborate a little more on the Norm situation and what you did to rectify it? I am having a hard time understanding what /.Abs@x_^2:>x^2 does. I found that it is called RuleDelayed, so is it replacing |x|^2 with x^2 each time you call it?

And for two, why do we not want to call Grad with {r}? Is it because r is technically {x,y}, so I would end up calling {{x,y}} which does not make sense?

Comment: Little update: I just made the changes you did and my vector plot works! Thank you so much, I cannot express how helpful this is, I have been stumped for over at least two weeks on this.

Comment: No problem.  Your reasoning about {{x,y}} is exactly right.  blah/.Abs@x_^2:>x^2 is a substitution.  `/.` is called [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), `Abs@x_^2` is the pattern.  `x_` is a `Blank`.

Comment: Mathematica takes the derivative of `Abs` if it is present, which is not desirable in this case.  It is introduced by `Norm`, so either roll your own Norm function or just remove the Abs.